# IotHubTrigger Is not working in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am getting issue IoTHubtrigger in azure function, Befor eit was working fine but suddenly it stops to triggered in azure function.
Here is my azure function Code:

```
`using IoTHubTrigger = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.EventHubTriggerAttribute;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
namespace TestIot
{  
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "IoTHubEndpoint")]EventData message, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes())}");
        }
    }
}`
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

can someone help me with this issue everything i configured in proper way but still not getting message in azure function.
If some help me with my issue it would be really appreciated.

I am trying to trigger IoT Hub message in azure function but still not getting any message on azure function ,when i try to send message form simulator device message reached to IOTHUB but not triggering in azure function.

Comment: for IotHubTrigger  in Azure Function Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743156/azure-functions-how-to-set-up-iothubtrigger-for-my-iothub-messages)

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466625/problems-with-azure-function-app-triggered-by-iot-hub-using-visual-studio-code)

Comment: with [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1166602/tutorial-for-creating-iot-hub-triggered-azure-func)

Answer (score 0):

- Using this Azure Functions how to set up IoTHubTrigger for [IoTHub messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743156/azure-functions-how-to-set-up-iothubtrigger-for-my-iothub-messages).

> ```c
> private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
>  [FunctionName("Function1")]
>   public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger(“messages/events”, Connection = “IoTHubEndpoint”)]EventData message, TraceWriter log)  
> {  
> log.Info($“C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes())}”);  
> }
> ```

- Azure IoT Hub trigger for Azure [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Ccsharp-script%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) .Rebuild and run the soultion again.

**In Azure Portal:**

[image]

[image]

- For More details refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261554/azure-functions-iothubtrigger-but-it-will-not-trigger).

Comment: Hi @Sampath 
Still not working in local even not getting any message in azure function. I followed properly those links which you mentioned.
Using V4  and .net6

Comment: Refer  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1166602/tutorial-for-creating-iot-hub-triggered-azure-func) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466625/problems-with-azure-function-app-triggered-by-iot-hub-using-visual-studio-code)